# MSDN simulate interrupt behavior

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, interrupt, msdn

I am trying to develop a embedded HW simulator by Visual studio 2010 with WINAPI.
I met problem when I tried to emulate interrupt...
The interrupt behavior acts as follows...
while a threadA is working and meanwhile there comes an interrupt,
so threadA will be hold and jumps to execute the ISR function, after 
the ISR function has been done, threadA can be resumed and keep working...

I tried to simulate this action by multithread
so there is a thread called interrupt-thread, which will suspend threadA and
do the ISR operation and then resume threadA, just like the below code...

but the problem is that my code will be stucked when calling sespendthread()
the previous printf("a") can be seen, but the printf("b") can not...

Is there any other ways to simulate interrupt with MSDN?
I considered about using singals and signalhandler to solve this question,
but it looks like windows signal can not be sent to specific thread,
only can be sent to specific process...

```
HANDLE thd_main;
HANDLE thd_int;
HANDLE Array_Of_Thread[2];

thd_main(){
    while(1){
      /* polling for jobs and do specific operation */
    }
}

thd_int(){
  while(1){
    if (WaitForSingleObject(g_timer, infinite) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
      printf("a");
      suspendthread(thd_main);
      printf("b");
      /* ISR operation */
      resumethread(thd_main);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  thd_main = CreateThread( NULL, 0, 
           Thread_main, NULL, 0, NULL); 

  thd_int = CreateThread( NULL, 0, 
           Thread_int, NULL, 0, NULL); 
  Array_Of_Thread[0] = thd_main;
  Array_Of_Thread[1] = thd_int;
  WaitForMultipleObjects( 3, Array_Of_Thread_Handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
  closehandle(thd_main);
  closehandle(thd_int);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use Suspend/ResumeThread to do thread synchronization!
Mainly these functions are present for debugging purpose. See MSDN documentation

See documentation for [SuspendThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> This function is primarily designed for use by debuggers It is not
>   intended to be used for thread synchronization.

The main problem is that you never know were you block a thread. Maybe it just uses resources that are locked by this thread. Than you may get deadlocks. Specially in the thread start phase and using CRT objects may cause such deadlock problems. But even if you use your synchronization objects you may fail.